# Java read serial data for given time period.

Tags: java, embedded, serial-port, bufferedreader

I have a function that reads serial data from an embedded device. My program shows a picture and a title and basically the device acts as a buzzer for a game. Is there a way to check for serial data for lets say 5 seconds and if nothing was received to continue with the code (go to the next picture and title). My current function looks like this.

```
    public String getUARTLine(){
        String inputLine = null;

        try{
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            inputLine = input.readLine();
            if (inputLine.length() == 0)
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e){
                //System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
                return null;
            }
        return inputLine;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start reading data from serialPort and start a timer in other thread. Something like this:

```
class ReadItWithTimeLimit implements Runnable {
   int miliSeconds;
   BufferedReader reader;
   public ReadItWithTimeLimit (BufferedReader reader, int miliSeconds) {
       this.miliSeconds = miliSeconds;
       this.reader = reader;
   }

   public void run() {
       Thread.sleep(miliSeconds);
       this.reader.close();
   }
}
```

So you can call it from your code:

```
// ... 
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
new Thread(new ReadItWithTimeLimit(input, 5000)).start();
inputLine = input.readLine();
// ...
```

This code is without excaption handling, so it requires some finalization work...

Comment: This only reads data once, it doesn't let you read it for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the buffer. Start a read on the input stream yourself and in a different thread count 5 seconds. After that, close the stream (that will cause the read function to return -1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use a separate timer thread that triggers the timeout that closes the input stream (that will cause input.readLine() to come back with an IOException). Or you can use [java.nio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html). However I personally prefer the first method.